# Calling a form's load event when form is already loaded but has gained focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am creating a bike booking system in VB using winforms.  I have two forms: frmBikeHire and frmBikeBookingsEdit.

On each form is a button with a click event to show and give focus to the other form.

```
frmBikeBookingsEdit.MdiParent = frmMDI_Main
frmBikeBookingsEdit.Show()
frmBikeBookingsEdit.Focus()
```

And

```
frmBikeHire.MdiParent = frmMDI_Main
frmBikeHire.Show()
frmBikeHire.Focus()
```

When a single form is open, the show command opens the other form and the load events from that form are run (refreshing the form).  When the second form is already open, then the focus command brings the second form to the front.  I also want the load events to run after the focus command so that the form is refreshed.  Is there a simple way to re-run the load command?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the `Activated` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked this one out myself...

I have made the refresh form commands that are called on the load event, by changing them to Public Subs and then calling the refresh commands before bringing the form back into focus:

```
    frmBikeBookingsEdit.MdiParent = frmMDI_Main
    frmBikeBookingsEdit.refreshBookingDetailsGrid()
    frmBikeBookingsEdit.refreshBookingsListGrid()
    frmBikeBookingsEdit.Show()
    frmBikeBookingsEdit.Focus()
```